# Dynamic height table cell in IOS with multiple labels

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

I'm struggling to make a cell resize it self... I have a stack view pinned Top, Right, Bottom and Left, plus 3 labels with 'lines' options defined as 0, but it only works if the first label is with that property at 0... I've posted a image that describes my problem. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently the problem was the 'distribution' property of the StackView... Changing it to 'Equal Spacing' instead 'Fill proportionally' fixed it... Thanks!

Comment: When the string has more content than which it can accomodate in single line, will it appear as multiline ?

Comment: @AlenAlexander You should set the number of lines property of the label as 0